# How to upload a JSON file to Azure blob storage using python?

Tags: python, json, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am not much familiar with python. I tried a code and it's not working.
My project is to download GH ARCHIVE data to local disk and then write a python script to upload in azure blob storage.
I download the GH ARCHIVE data in notebook++ as JSON file. Now I am trying to write a code. Please help with the code.

```
pip install azure-storage-blob


from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient


import requests

gh_archive_url = "https://data.gharchive.org/"

storage_account_name = "storage-name"

storage_account_key = (<container_string>)

container_name =(< "container_name">)

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=f"https://{storage_name}.blob.core.windows.net", credential=container_string

container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
```